# Manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function React-Materialize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I am having trouble getting rid of this warning:

> You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function for the
>   `large` prop on `Button`. This is deprecated and will not work in the
>   next major version. You may be seeing this warning due to a
>   third-party PropTypes library.

For example, I have a simple **Header Component** as so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button, Icon} from 'react-materialize';

export default class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button node='a' waves='light'><Icon right>file_cloud</Icon>button</Button>
    );
  }
}
```

Versions that I am using:

```
"react": "^0.14.3",
"react-materialize": "^0.15.2"
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. I'm pretty sure this warning related to the library you are using `react-materialize`. If I were you, I would have opened an issue in project and notified developers about this warning https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize/issues

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looked like I just had to update the react library

Answer (score 1):

Ok solved it. It looked like I had update my React Library:

```
"react": "^15.3.1",
"react-dom": "^15.3.1 ",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.1"
```